# How do I query FreeTextTable() using Entity Frameworks?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, freetexttable

I understand using `FromSqlRaw()` to pass in the query that returns the list of records that `FreeTextTable` returns (PK, Rank). But how do I get a List of those records?

I think [Keyless Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations) is the way to do this. But everything I've read on these says there's a matching underlying view for the type. In this case, there is no view.

Do I have to [fall back to ADO.NET calls](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5321286/Executing-Raw-SQL-Queries-using-Entity-Framework-C)? I'm very familiar with ADO.NET so no problem using it. But if there's an EF approach, I'd prefer that.